# Ghost-Tag "javascript"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273890/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-for-primitives-in-c) pretends being tagged as [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

[image: question tagged as javascript]

The [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21273890/revisions) shows that the question was originally tagged as [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [compare](/questions/tagged/compare), and there is no edit which changed the tags.

If I edit the question and remove the tag, the edit is successful (200), but it does not do anything.

Comment: I *added* a tag, removed the extra tag and now it is gone.

Comment: @rene I was confused about this, too. The `edit` button should be disabled then.

Comment: @rene nope, protected is not locked, users can edit as usual including 1 rep users and anonymous visitors. They can't *answer* that's all.

Comment: Really weird, there's no trace for that tag in the question. Tried Data Explorer as well, showing only the original two tags. Real ghost! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea what caused the problem; most likely a caching error as the tag was added then removed in a grace edit, with the page cache missing that last update.

I resolved it by forcing a new revision; I [*added* a dummy tag, then removed that tag again](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21273890/8) in a grace period edit. This flushed the cache and the tag is now gone.